# theano has different results on CPU and GPU

Tags: gpu, cpu, theano, theano-cuda

I wrote a Theano machine learning program. But I got two absolutely different results between on CPU and on GPU.

Below is the log.(only a tiny part of log)

[result on GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1JVx.jpg)

[result on CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6mXI.jpg)

The loss function will quickly decrease and then converg to 0.2 on CPU.

However, the loss function will increase and finally become NaN on GPU.

What mistakes may be in my program? Or what should I take into attention? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that CPU is using `float64` (double precision) and the GPU is using `float32` (single precision)? Here you can look up the configuration flags: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html

Comment: But...I have used "warn_float64=raise" and nothing happened. I have set "floatX = float32".

Comment: Did you set `floatX=float32` for GPU _and_ CPU explicitly? Like `THEANO_FLAGS='floatX=float32,device=cpu...`

Comment: Yes, I did. And the command is
'THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=cpu,floatX=float32 python train.py'
'THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu0,floatX=float32 python train.py'

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread... 
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/511
Basically adding;

```
optimizer_excluding=cudnn
```

in the .theanorc solved it for me, but solution runs a slower.